# which package can be an alternative for mongooes dummy

Tags: node.js, security, mongoose, prisma, npm-vulnerabilities

```
const dummy = require('mongoose-dummy');
```

I want replace this package to its similar one in my code, its dependent module mpath and uuid creating issue. Is there any alternative package.

Comment: what issues would `mpath` and `uuid` probably create? They are both used in millions of projects as direct or indirect dependency. So if they are causing issues for you, the problem is probably on your site.

Comment: Its is creating Prisma vulnerabilities

Comment: @TrangD What? Explain please...

Comment: Could you please elaborate on which prisma vulnerabilities you are talking about? You could create a Bug Report to submit the vulnerabilities if needed:
https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new?assignees=&labels=kind%2Fbug&template=bug_report.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [mongoose-data-faker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-data-faker) package to generate random data based on your Mongoose schema.

Another alternative is to use the [faker](https://fakerjs.dev/) package to generate data.